# Exponential diophantine equation: $2p^2-6p+7=3^n$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I'm trying to prove that the only integer positive solutions are $(n=1,\ p=1)$ and $(n=3,\ p=5)$. Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Is $p$ a prime?

Comment: @wythagoras, not everything is prime which denoted by $p$

Comment: @wythagoras Not necessarily. Anyway it would be enough to have a proof for prime $p$.

Comment: Substituting $p=k+2$ gives the equation $2k(k+1)=3^n-3$. I think, I saw it somewhere...

Comment: where did you get this???????????????????????????

Comment: @Will, I'm trying to prove that if a number written as 2013 in base $b$ ($b>3$) has only "3" and "11" as prime factors (both written in base $b$, of course), then $b=4$ or $b=6$.

Comment: @Dietrich, yes, the quadratic form $2p^2 - 6pq+7q^2$ is $SL_2 \mathbb Z$ equivalent to $2x^2 + 2 x y + 3 y^2.$ This certainly does primitively  represent all $3^n$ with $n$ odd, but it becomes a mess when we force $y=1,$ or $q=1,$ and surely has finitely many solutions then.

Comment: After a web search I could find the solution of the original problem: see [link](http://uz.sns.it/~fvenez/dioph_2013.pdf). It involves solving the equation $y^2+5=2\cdot3^\alpha$, but the solution proposed there is rather complex.

Comment: The solution there is not diffuclt - in comparison to similar Diophantine equations of type $ax^2+bx+c=y^n$.

Comment: You've missed the solution $(a,n)=(2,1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p=a$ be any integer. $(2a-3)^2+5=2\cdot 3^n$. Now $3$ cases:

- $n=3k$. Then $(2(2a-3))^2+20=\left(2\cdot 3^k\right)^3$. But $x^2+20=y^3$ has $2$ integral solutions $(x,y)=(\pm 14,6)$ (http://tnt.math.se.tmu.ac.jp/simath/MORDELL/), so $(a,k)=(5,1),(-2,1)$, so $(a,n)=(5,3),(-2,3)$.
- $n=3k+1$. Then $(6(2a-3)))^2+180=\left(2\cdot 3^{k+1}\right)^3$. But $x^2+180=y^3$ has $4$ integral solutions $(x,y)=(\pm 6,6),(\pm 573,69)$, so $(a,n)=(2,1),(1,1)$.
- $n=3k+2$. Then $(18(2a-3))^2+1620=\left(2\cdot 3^{k+2}\right)^3$, no solutions.